# How to quick view tables in DataGrip?

Tags: datagrip

In sql express I could setup query shortcuts, so I simply create a "Select * from " shortcut and when I press it with the table name selected it shows me the select result

There's any way I can quick view the table content selecting only the table name in a script?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If I got you right, there are several ways to do what you want:

1. Ctrl+N (Cmd+O for Mac) → type the name of the table, press Enter
2. If the cursor is on the name of the table inside the script, press F4.
3. If the cursor is on the name of the table inside the DB explorer, you can double-click it or press F4.
4. If you are in the query console, the quick way to type "SELECT * FROM" is to type "sel" and press Tab. Then put the name of the table and run the query.
5. In any place, whether it's SQL or database explorer, press Ctrl+Q (F1 for Mac) and you will see the quick documentation window.

Answer (score 12):

Another quick solution can be to put your cursor in the name of your table and press CTRL+Q, this will open the quick documentation, it will show the table structure with the first 10 rows at the end.

I find this faster than running the query.

Comment: the best way for sure

Comment: FWIW, on my Mac F1 is the hotkey for this - probably depends on your hotkey scheme. Right-click and choose "Quick Documentation" works too.

Personally I found Ramin's answer below (double click on table name in left pane) the most convenient.

Comment: @mucio. I just want to say that you are my hero for the week. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Double-clicking on a table in the left pane will open the data for the table.