# How to quickly generate SELECT statement with all columns for a table in DataGrip?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datagrip

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), you can right-click on a table, then go to `Script Table as` -> `SELECT To`, and then choose a destination for the generated script.

Is there anything similar in DataGrip, or can one be custom created in some way?

The reason I find this useful is because I often find that I'm working with a table with a lot of columns, and I want to select all but a few of them. So it's easier to just have it generate the SELECT statement with all the columns explicitly listed out, so that I can just go through and delete the ones I don't want.

Currently, my workaround in DataGrip is to right-click the table, then choose `Copy DDL`. This generates the CREATE TABLE statement, which lists out all the columns, but it also includes the column definitions. So I have to do a regex replace or run a macro to get rid of the extra info, which is kind of a pain. Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: you can script this behavior just querying system tables.

Comment: For those looking to just quickly preview the table, https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/38742700 provides an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In DataGrip, as in other IntelliJ-based IDEs, everything is about source editing. What you want can be achieved this way:

- Open console
- Start typing `sel`, you'll get completion popup (if not, hit `Ctrl+Space`)
- Choose `sel` here, which is live template for `SELECT` statement
- `SELECT` statement will be generated, asking for table name and column list [image]
- Select desired table from completion, as column list provide `*`
- Then hit `Alt+Enter` on asterisk and select `Expand column list` [image]

I suggest you to look through https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/features/

Answer (score 18):

In DataGrip 2018.3 you can use *postfix completion*. This is the flexible way to get needed queries.

Try typing

```sql
SELECT %table_name%.from
SELECT %table_name%.afrom
SELECT %table_name%.join
```

And this will be expanded to the needed queries. In the case of `from` completion you'll be able to write columns.

This makes writing SQL more logical: first, you point table, then columns.

See gif:
[image]

Comment: [`.cfrom`/`.afrom`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/auto-completing-code.html#postfix_completion) are helpful.